# New Window gets created on Click but not on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension development. Trying my hand at my first one.

I am trying to write an extension that performs a certain action on every page load.

It is required to send a post request upon every page load. I use an ajax request to do so. Upon successfully sending the request, I want to open a popup/ new - window.

Here is my manifest file

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Coupons",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Yay! Coupons",
    "icons": { "16": "images/carbs16.png",
               "48": "images/carbs48.png",
               "128": "images/carbs128.png" },
               "browser_action": {
               "default_title": "Coupons ! Yay",
    "default_icon": "images/carbs48.png",
    "default_popup":"start.html"
},
"permissions":
    ["https://example.com/"],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
    "content_scripts": 
    [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"], 
            "js": ["jquery-2.1.3.min.js","myscript.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"  
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my myscript.js file

```
$.post("https://example.com",
{
    product_name: url,
    desc:"Yo",
    price: "22"
},
function(data){
    //alert("yay")
    chrome.windows.create({'url':'void.html','type':'popup'},function(window){  

    })  
});
```

Here is my start.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am facing is as follows :

The request gets sent successfully and a new window gets created when I click the icon for my chrome extension in the browser.

However, the aim is for exactly that to happen on every page load. But in that case, the request gets sent ( which means the file executes ) on page load. However, the new window I want to create doesn't show up.

Any ideas on why that could be happening will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason that `myscript.js` is in both `start.html` and in `context_scripts`? The first case is for the icon click and the second case is for the individual tabs.

Comment: @peterdotjs yes, I had put it in both files just to analyze why it was behaving differently on clicking and loading

Comment: @peterdotjs also could you tell me where in my content_script would I add window.open or chrome.windows

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `chrome.windows` is undefined in the content script. If you look in your console you should see an error when you load a new tab.

It works the first time because you are running `myscript.js` from the browser action popup which has access to `chrome.windows`.

If you just want to do this action on load of a page, the content script alone will do the job. You won't need `start.html` and `browser_action` object can be removed from `manifest.json`.

In addition you'll need to modify the content script to use `window.open` instead of `chrome.windows`.

Adding @abrahams comment:

`window.open` will likely get blocked by the popup blocker if it's not triggered by a user action. The solution might be to post a message to a background script and use chrome.windows from there.

Comment: I would guess `window.open` will get blocked by the popup blocker if it's not triggered by a user action. The solution might be to post a message to a background script and use `chrome.windows` from there.

Comment: @abraham Could you tell me how I would do that using a background script ? I am fairly new to both javascript and making an extension

Comment: @shahharsh2603 check out [Simple one-time reqeusts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple)